# How to configure Android mediaCodec to create a I frame only stream?

Tags: android, video, android-mediacodec

I found in some Android Phones, set "i-frame-interval" to 0 can create a I frame only stream. But in others, like huawei Mate 9, the result is IPPPPPPPPP...

Are there any universal methods to do this?

Answer (score 0):

using PARAMETER_KEY_REQUEST_SYNC_FRAME